# ¿Como hago para mostrar en php con JavaScript, mediante un <select> una coordenada que se encuentre almacenada en base de datos en el campo coords?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Actualmente me encuentro realizando un aplicativo web sobre php, el cual captura las coordenadas del api de google maps, posteriormente lo guardo en una base de datos en el campo coords.

Ahora solo necesito poder mostrar esto nuevamente en el mapa del api de google maps, esto para hacerlo mediante un , al momento de seleccionarlo, me pinte sobre el mapa las coordenadas y me ubique sobre el punto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debes mostrar el código que has intentado y dónde te encuentras con problemas, se trata de ayudar con el desarrollo no de hacértelo. Lo que pides es muy amplio, Google Maps recoge información de coordenadas en el mismo formato numérico que las proporciona.

Comment: Cual es el error que te marca?, que soluciones haz intentado, deberías mostrar como lo estas haciendo para poderte ayudar con tu problema.